# Spring Security : Call from external website unable to redirect to our application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, payment-gateway

We are developing a Spring based web application, which is using Spring Security 3.2.3. We are integrating with an external payment gateway (`Paytm`) for accepting user's payments. Following is a scenario where we are facing issue:

1. User logs in to the application (it's an `HTTP` non-S app) and clicks on a button which
   redirects him to the payment gateway (`Paytm` payment gateway - it's `HTTPS` url).
2. For `Paytm` integration, we have configured a callback URL i.e. index page of our application (eg. `http://server:port/app/index.jsp`). User completes the payment and `Paytm` redirects the control back to our Spring application.
3. When `Paytm` tries to call our app's index page (eg. `http://server:port/app/index.jsp`), it fails and in Chrome debugger, we could see a `403 Forbidden` response.
4. However, this scenario works well in `Mozilla Firexfox` and `IE 11`. The issue in only seen in `Google Chrome` and `Opera`browsers.
5. We tried by providing some other website in callback URL (like `https://google.com`) and the redirection went successful.

What we are suspecting is it might be some config issue or missing setting in Spring Security, but which we are not sure of.

This is our Spring Security config:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- Un-comment when authorization is implemented -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" />
        <logout logout-success-url="${login.page.url}" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select gu.email, gu.password, gu.enabled from global_user gu,global_organization_user gou, global_organization go where email=? and gu.enabled=1 and gu.is_deleted=0 and gou.user_id = gu.id and gou.organization_id=go.id and go.current_stage='ACTIVE' and go.is_deleted=0"
                authorities-by-username-query="select u.email, r.role_id from global_user u, security_user_role r
                where u.id = r.user_id and u.email=?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
    <beans:bean id="successHandler"
        class="app.server.security.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="failureHandler"
        class="app.server.security.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler" />

    <beans:bean id="expressionHandler"
        class="app.server.security.authorization.CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="authorizationEvaluator">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authorizationEvaluator"
        class="app.server.security.authorization.AuthorizationEvaluator" />


    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
    </global-method-security>

    <http pattern="/rest/app/someurl**" security="none"/>
    // other URLs which are escaped from spring security
```

Any suggestions and pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is temporarily solved by redirecting the payment gateway response to an intermediate URL (we created a separate web project and provided its link). This intermediate URL then redirects the control to our Spring application.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue as op, but we managed to fix this by configuring our callback URL to use ***https*** instead of ***http***. However, this might not work for everyone since every payment gateway has different security control. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score -1):

This problem also solved at my site at localhost using https.
Add SSL certificate and try it.